# Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 with Exchange 2010 on the same OS

Tags: sql-server-2008, exchange-2010

We're getting conflicting recommendations by hardware suppliers for our new server.

We're looking to get SBS 2011 to run Exchange Server.  We also need SQL Server 2008 R2.

Some people say you need to virtualize the server and have Exchange running on one OS and SQL running on another.

Other people say that's overkill and you'll get better performance by running everything within the one OS.

This is for a small company of 8 users, by the way.

So, can the two be installed side by side or not?

Answer (score 2):

They can be installed side by side, and that's what I would do for a company your size.  I've done it before that way.  To me it's not worth the overhead of maintaining a different server.  What you'll want to do, though, is cap the memory that SQL Server uses to ensure that Exchange has enough memory to use.  You'll probably also want to look at putting enough disks in the server to let Exchange and SQL perform independent IO.  That is, separate volumes for Exchange, SQL Data, and SQL Logs at the minimum.

To set max memory in SQL do this:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
GO

reconfigure
GO

sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)',[some value in MB]
GO

reconfigure
GO
```

Of course, this assumes that you're not running a massive database.  I am also not an Exchange god by any stretch so there may be some further thoughts from those guys.

Comment: We run lots of databases some > 18GB in size

Comment: How many and what's your combined size?  18 GB is not massive if you have the right hardware.  Memory will be quite important, and if you're going to run side by side then capping SQL will definitely be something you want to do.

Comment: Around 15 databases and 25GB total size

Comment: You should have no problem with a side by side install then.  Just load your server up with memory and set the max memory option in SQL.  How much memory do you have in your server?

Comment: Speccing up the server at the moment, haven't bought it yet

Answer (score 0):

You are basically describing exactly what SBS was meant to do. It's designed for small companies like yours that need an all-in-one Windows based solution.

On the Exchange side, since it is so small, you don't really need to be splitting database and log files onto different disks, but if you are going to be using SQL heavily, then maybe it would be a good idea to keep the Exchange DBs and SQL DBs on a set of disks and the logs for both on another set.

Don't forget to factor in your backup/disaster recovery, since this will be a single server shop.